# makefile. Запуск сервера и клиента

Tags: c++, python, bash, golang

Привет.
Есть следующая структура:

1. Прилажка-сервер на python слушает браузер через сокет на порту 8081. Ждёт от него ответа. Браузер в данном случае -- клинет.
2. На Go реализован back-end. Здесь реализована начинка системы.
3. Дождавшись запроса от браузера, прилажка на python из первого пункта отвечает посылает запрос в начинку и ждёт ответа. После получения ответа запрос отправляется обратно в браузер.

Таким образом, есть некоторый шлюз на питоне, который считает статистику. Шлюз, как и начинка крутятся в бесконечном цикле.

Вопрос. Как реализовать makefile так, чтобы в нём компилилась и запускалась начинка системы и шлюз.

Я не могу это сделать, так как make-file линеен. Т.е. пока не отработает одна инструкция. Другая не запустится.

Comment: назначение make - это сборка проектов. вам же нужно управлять жизненным циклом. думаю, что вам подойдет вот это [Paver](https://github.com/paver/paver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make файл просто запускает команды в консоле.  Поэтому работает классический `&`

то есть, нужно писать что то вида

```
run:
    ./first &
    ./second &
    echo "все запущено и работает!"
```

ну или если сильно нужно - можно запустить в screen/tmux/ сервисом / docker.

```
run:
    screen ./first
    screen ./second &
    echo "все запущено и работает!"
```

плюс этого способа в том, что можно будет скрином подцепиться и посмотреть логи. Но можно и просто перенаправить вывод в файл.

И остается последний вопрос - а как сделать завершение? самый простой способ просто кильнуть по имени. Но можно сохранить PID запущенных процессов и задача сильно упрощается.